# Adding an action listener or if statement to JPane

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a GUI for a work related project and having some problems.

I want my GUI to have a JTextField and three buttons. I want the user to be able to type a certain number into the text field and then depending upon which button they click certain actions will be performed.

The problem I am encountering is my ActionListener with the JTextField does not appear to be working. When I test it out I get no result. Any help would be greatly appreciated, below is my code.

```
package nacha;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Testing 

{
    static  String code = null;
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int sixBatch1TotalCounter=1;
        int sixBatch1Total=2;
        int main = 1000001;




        final JTextField reasonCode = new JTextField(10);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();


p.add(new JLabel("<html>" +
                "Entry Detail: "+
                "<br>"+main+
                "<br>Entry Detail "+sixBatch1TotalCounter+" of "+sixBatch1Total+
                "<br><br>Please type 1-21 to apply reason code and addenda record to the entry detail record."+
                "<br>To omit displayed entry detail from the return, simply leave the input line blank and press enter."+
                "<br><br>Reason Code Descriptions:"+
                "<br>R01 - Insufficient Funds"+
                "<br>R02 - Account Closed"+
                "<br>R03 - No Account"+
                "<br>R04 - Invalid Account Number"+
                "<br>R05 - Unauthorized Debit to Consumer Account Using Corporate SEC Code"+
                "<br>R06 - Returned per ODFI Request"+
                "<br>R07 - Auth Revoked by Customer"+
                "<br>R08 - Payment Stopped"+
                "<br>R09 - Uncollected Funds"+
                "<br>R10 - Customer Advises Not Authorized"
                ));

        p.add(reasonCode);

        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Object[] choices = {"Next","Next Batch","Submit"};
        Object defaultChoice = choices[0];



        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, p, "Return Builder",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,choices,defaultChoice);

        reasonCode.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

                System.out.println(reasonCode.getText());

            }

        });



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the actionListener until showOptionDialog has returned, when the dialog has already been closed.   Also the whole thing should run from the EventThread.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am still a bit confused. I understand what you mean about the ActionListener but don't get what you mean by the event thread.

Comment: Why do you need an ActionListener on the text field if what you want to do is to take some action depending on which button of the OptionDialog is pressed?  And you aren't saving the result of the showOptionDialog call, so you don't have any way to determine  which button was pressed.

Comment: Your answer was enough to get me going in the right direction and I got it working. Thanks a lot!